# Partitioning Oracle tables used for logging

Tags: oracle10g, partitioning

I have an application that records activity in a table (Oracle 10g). The logging records should be kept for at least 30 days. I expect about 20 million rows to be added to this table every month.

The DBA suggested that the table be split in partitions containing one week of data. The weekly maintenance script would then delete the oldest partition (leaving only 4 weeks of data in the table).

What would be the best way of partitioning this logging table?

Comment: What are your criteria for deciding "best way"?  Query performance?  Minmising management overhead?  Downtime concerns?

Comment: It should be easy to remove (or migrate to datawarehouse) partitions with old data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partitioning a table isn't hard - it appears that you will be removing the data on a weekly basis, so the partition clauses will look like

```
PARTITION "P2009_45"  VALUES LESS THAN 
(TO_DATE(' 2009-11-02 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')),
 PARTITION "P2009_46"  VALUES LESS THAN 
(TO_DATE(' 2009-11-09 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')),
... etc
```

where your partitioning column is your date column of interest in the table.

Additional comments:

- If you can upgrade to 11g you can
  take advantage of interval
  partitioning, which is similar to
  this range partitioning, but Oracle
  will manage creating new partitions
  for you.
- If you're going to routinely drop off
  partitions, I would advise making all
  indexes on the table
  locally-partitioned to avoid the
  rebuilds that would be necessary with
  global partitions after partition
  operations.
- If you have a good idea of the number
  of log entries per month, and it
  stays relatively constant, you might
  consider using a sequence (as a primary key) that is
  capped at this number and then
  recycles back to 0.  Then your
  logging statements must become "MERGE
  INTO... " statements that either
  create a new row or overwrite the row
  if it exists.  This only guarantees
  that you'll retain the number of rows
  allowed by the sequence max value and
  NOT a certain time interval, but this
  might be an alternative to
  partitioning (which as DvE points
  out, is an extra-expense option)

Answer (score 1):

The most likely partitioning scheme would be to [range-partition](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7002.htm#i2153312) your data on the creation date. Each week you would create a new partition and drop the oldest one. The impact will depend on how this table is used / indexed.

Since it is a logging table perhaps it is not indexed, in that case dropping a partition will have little impact: referencing objects won't be invalidated, the drop will be just require a partition lock (and the oldest partition shouldn't be inserted at that time).

If the table is indexed, you will have to decide if your indexes will be global or partitionned. Global indexes will have to be rebuilt when you drop a partition (which takes time, although 20M rows is still manageable). You can use the [`UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_3001.htm#i2150023) clause to keep the indexes valid after the partition drop.

Local indexes will be partitionned like the table and may be less efficient than global indexes (index range scans will have to scan each local index instead of a common index if you do not query by date). These indexes won't have to be updated after a partition drop.

Answer (score 0):

20 million rows every month and you only have to keep 30 days of data? (That's about a months worth).

Even with 12 months worth of data it wouldn't be hard to query this table (as one big table) with the correct index.
Inserting is no problemen either with 1 row in the logging table or 20 million.

Partitioning in Oracle is also a feature that needs to be paid for if I'm correct, so it's costly too (if you don't have a license already).

Comment: It's a requirement by the DBA